# How to get an image-map working in a combination of a magnifier (glass) on top of a responsive image using HTML, CSS and JS (image, image-map, glass)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, click

Trying to resolve Responsive Image + (Responsive) Image-Map + Magnifier (js) and clicking being passed to what is specified in the area of the image-map.

See [this test site](https://afterall.ddns.me/zafasia/index.html) and click on Original, Mag or MagClick on the Home - please note this runs on a RPI4 and performance is what it is ;-). The idea is to set a free and anonymous site based on "themed naming" for people with Aphasia.

Working: the Responsive Image with Image Map without Magnifier, the Magnifier as per W3Schools example, the pointer in the Magnifier, passing the pointer click to the Image.

Not Working: the click on the Magnifier/Responsive_Image cannot start the action indicated in the image-map for the specific area

I can get the Magnifier to be clickable and sound a beep when clicking on the image.

```
    /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
    glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    
    /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
    // glass.addEventListener("click", beep);
    //img.addEventListener("click", beep);
    img.addEventListener("click", function(){beep();imgmap.click();});
    // img.addEventListener("click", function(){imgmap.addListener('click', tocaudio);img.removeListener('click', event["listener"]);});
    
    /*and also for touch screens:*/
    glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
```

I cannot pass this click to the underlying (Responsive) image-map for the execution of the expected function specified within the image-map itself. The beep works but cannot pass the click to the area/imagemap.

```
img.addEventListener("click",function() {beep(); imgmag.click();});

img.addEventListener("click", function(){imgmap.addListener('click', tocaudio);
img.removeListener('click', event["listener"]);});
```

Any hints?

The complete code (I am not a programmer so there is a lot of space for optimization):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<style>
  @charset "UTF-8";
    
  * {box-sizing: border-box;}
    
  .header {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 5px 5px;
  }
    
    .header a {
      float: left;
      color: black;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 5px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14px; 
      line-height: 15px;
      border-radius: 2px;
    }
    
    .header a.logo {
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    .header a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .header a.active {
      background-color: dodgerblue;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .header-right {
      float: right;
    }

    table {
      display: table;
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 2px;
      border-color: gray;
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 100%;
    }   

    td {
      text-align: center;
    }
  
  .img-magnifier-container {
    position:relative;
    /* Added Parent */
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  
  .img-magnifier-glass {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: none;
    /*Set the size of the magnifier glass:*/
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
    /* width: 100px;
    height: 100px; */
    /* Added Child */
    pointer-events: none;
  }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /* Lista de Palavras - Atenção nem todas têm audio = 
  ["ventoinha","teto","parede","moldura","pintura","vaso""cornija",
  "lareira","fogo","salvafagulhas","corrim\u00e3o","escadas","degrau",
  "secretaria","tapate","cadeirao"]; */
  var palArray = ["ventoinha","parede","pintura","fogo","escadas","secretaria"];
  
  /* Variaveis da pagina */ 
  var palcerta = "";
  var paltocada = "";
  var sms = "";
  var toto = 0;
  var certas = 0;
  
  window.addEventListener("load", function inicio(){
    // wait 1s after full page load
    setTimeout(palavrarnd, 1000, palArray);
  });
  
  /* random Int from Interval */
  function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) { // min and max included 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  }
  
  /* audio da palavra indicada */
  function tocaudio(thisfile) {
    var palt = thisfile;
    paltocada = palt;
    var palc = palcerta;
    if (palt == palc && palc != "") {
      document.getElementById("textosms").innerHTML = "<font color='green'>CORRETO: "+palt+" == "+palc+"</font>";
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palt+".mp3");
      audio.play();
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palt+".ogg");
      audio.play();
      certas = certas + 1;
      document.getElementById("sumario").innerHTML = "Resultado: "+certas+" de "+toto;
    } else if (palt != palc && palc != "") {
      document.getElementById("textosms").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>ERRO: "+palt+" != "+palc+"</font>";
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palt+".mp3");
      audio.play();
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palt+".ogg");
      audio.play();
    } else {    
      document.getElementById("textosms").innerHTML = "<font color='blue'>NULO: "+palt+"</font>";
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palt+".mp3");
      audio.play();
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palt+".ogg");
      audio.play();
    }
    paltocada = "dummy";
    /* palcerta = ""; */
    /* starts new master 5s after but waits previous */
    setTimeout(sleep, 3000, 1000);
    setTimeout(palavrarnd, 5000, palArray);
  }
  
  /* Com base na lista de palavras, analisa escolha */ 
  function palavrarnd(lista){
    var palc = palcerta;
    var palt = paltocada;
    if (palt == "" && palc == "") {    
      palc = lista[randomIntFromInterval(0, 5)];
      palcerta = palc;
      document.getElementById("textosms").innerHTML = palc;
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palc+".mp3");
      audio.play();
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palc+".ogg");
      audio.play();
      toto = toto +1;
  } else if (palt == "" && palc != "") {
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palc+".mp3");
      audio.play();
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palc+".ogg");
      audio.play();
      document.getElementById("textosms").innerHTML = palc;
    } else {
      var oldpalc = palc;
      do {      
        palc = lista[randomIntFromInterval(0, 5)];
      } while (palc == oldpalc);
      palcerta = palc;
      palt = "";
      paltocada = palt; 
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palc+".mp3");
      audio.play();
      var audio = new Audio("./Sounds/"+palc+".ogg");
      audio.play();
      toto = toto +1;
      document.getElementById("textosms").innerHTML = palc;
    }
    document.getElementById("sumario").innerHTML = "Resultado: "+certas+" de "+toto;
  }
  
  /* Sleep */
  function sleep(milliseconds) {
    document.getElementById("textosms").innerHTML = "==> A sincronizar <==";
    const date = Date.now();
    let currentDate = null;
    do {
      currentDate = Date.now();
    } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
  }
  
  function play(thisfile) {
      var audio = new Audio(thisfile+".mp3");
      audio.play();
      var audio = new Audio(thisfile+".ogg");
      audio.play();
  }

  function beep() {
      var snd = new Audio('https://www.soundjay.com/misc/censor-beep-01.mp3');
      snd.play();
  }

  /* Magnifier Function and Children */
  function magnify(imgID, zoom) {
    var img, imgmap, glass, w, h, bw;
  
    img = document.getElementById(imgID);
    imgmap = document.getElementById('image-map');
    
    /*create magnifier glass:*/
    glass = document.createElement("DIV");
    glass.setAttribute("class", "img-magnifier-glass");
    
    /*insert magnifier glass:*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(glass, img);
    
    /*set background properties for the magnifier glass:*/
    glass.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    glass.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
    glass.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * zoom) + "px " + (img.height * zoom) + "px";
    bw = 3;
    w = glass.offsetWidth / 2;
    h = glass.offsetHeight / 2;
    
    /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
    glass.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    // imgmap.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMagnifier);
    
    /*execute a function when someone moves the magnifier glass over the image:*/
    // glass.addEventListener("click", beep);
    //img.addEventListener("click", beep);
    img.addEventListener("click", (z)=>{beep(); z.stopPropagation(); imgmap.click();});
    // img.addEventListener("click", function(){beep(); imgmap.addListener('click', tocaudio);img.removeListener('click', event["listener"]);});
    // imgmap.addEventListener("click", beep);
    
    /*and also for touch screens:*/
    glass.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
    // imgmap.addEventListener("touchmove", moveMagnifier);
  
    function moveMagnifier(e) {
      var pos, x, y;
      /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image*/
      e.preventDefault();
      /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
      pos = getCursorPos(e);
      x = pos.x;
      y = pos.y;
      /*prevent the magnifier glass from being positioned outside the image:*/
      if (x > img.width - (w / zoom)) {x = img.width - (w / zoom);}
      if (x < w / zoom) {x = w / zoom;}
      if (y > img.height - (h / zoom)) {y = img.height - (h / zoom);}
      if (y < h / zoom) {y = h / zoom;}
      /*set the position of the magnifier glass:*/
      glass.style.left = (x - w) + "px";
      glass.style.top = (y - h) + "px";
      /*display what the magnifier glass "sees":*/
      glass.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + ((x * zoom) - w + bw) + "px -" + ((y * zoom) - h + bw) + "px";
    }
  
    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0, y = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      y = e.pageY - a.top;
      /*consider any page scrolling:*/
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      y = y - window.pageYOffset;
      return {x : x, y : y};
    }

  }
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
        <a href="/zafasia" class="logo">Zafasia <img src="/zafasia/zafasia.png" alt="Zafasia" height="15" width="15"></a>
        <div class="header-right">
          <a href="/zafasia">Home</a>
          <a href="girl.html">Original</a>
          <a href="Mag.html">Mag</a>
          <a class="active" href="MagClick.html">MagClick</a>
          <a href="/zafasia/about.html">About</a>
        </div>
</div>

<center>
  <table>
    <tr>
    <td id=palavratocada>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Palavra <a href="javascript:palavrarnd(palArray)"><img src="/zafasia/Imagens/soundbw.png" alt="Audio" title="Audio" width="15" height="15"></a></td>
    <td>Test <a href="javascript:beep()"><img src="/zafasia/Imagens/soundbw.png" alt="Audio" title="Audio" width="15" height="15"></a></td>
    <td id=textosms>&nbsp;</td>
    <td id=palavracerta>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>    
</center>

<div class="img-magnifier-container">
  <!img id="myimage" src="/zafasia/Sala/Imagens/OPD-Sala.png" width="100%" height="auto">
  <img id="map" src="/zafasia/Sala/Imagens/OPD-Sala.png" width="100%" height="auto" usemap="#map-mask">
</div>

<map name="map-mask">
  <area shape="circle" coords="327,48,39" style="outline:none" alt="ventoinha" title="ventoinha" href="javascript:tocaudio('ventoinha')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="172,61,39" style="outline:none" alt="teto" title="teto" href="javascript:tocaudio('teto')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="97,111,33" style="outline:none" alt="parede" title="parede" href="javascript:tocaudio('parede')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="36,125,25" style="outline:none" alt="moldura" title="moldura" href="javascript:tocaudio('moldura')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="40,198,28" style="outline:none" alt="pintura" title="pintura" href="javascript:tocaudio('pintura')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="103,242,24" style="outline:none" alt="vaso" title="vaso" href="javascript:tocaudio('vaso')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="63,273,24" style="outline:none" alt="cornija" title="cornija" href="javascript:tocaudio('cornija')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="102,303,22" style="outline:none" alt="lareira" title="lareira" href="javascript:tocaudio('lareira')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="56,330,25" style="outline:none" alt="fogo" title="fogo" href="javascript:tocaudio('fogo')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="113,417,19" style="outline:none" alt="salvafagulhas" title="salvafagulhas" href="javascript:tocaudio('salvafagulhas')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="77,422,15" style="outline:none" alt="corrimao" title="corrimao" href="javascript:tocaudio('corrimao')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="73,548,22" style="outline:none" alt="escadas" title="escadas" href="javascript:tocaudio('escadas')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="58,590,20" style="outline:none" alt="degrau" title="degrau" href="javascript:tocaudio('degrau')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="272,586,24" style="outline:none" alt="secretaria" title="secretaria" href="javascript:tocaudio('secretaria')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="276,413,28" style="outline:none" alt="tapete" title="tapete" href="javascript:tocaudio('tapete')"/>
  <area shape="circle" coords="225,361,31" style="outline:none" alt="cadeirao" title="cadeirao" href="javascript:tocaudio('cadeirao')"/>
</map>
  
<table>
  <tr><td id=sumario>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
  
<script type="text/javascript">
  /* Initiate Magnify Function with the id of the image, and the strength of the magnifier glass:*/
  // magnify("myimage", 3);
  magnify("map", 3);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have used these links and a few others...

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49332600/how-can-i-adapt-a-javascript-magnifier-to-allow-it-to-click-on-an-imagemap`](https://stackoverflow.com)

[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033380/how-to-trigger-onclick-of-underlayed-image`](https://stackoverflow.com)

Magnifier comes from:

[https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_magnifier_glass.asp](https://stackoverflow.com)